# Respect/Validation email() don't work

Tags: php, post, validation, respect-validation

I use Respect/Validation and when I use email()...the problem is:

if I validate a string: `validator::email()->validate('hello@helloworld.com');` it work!

if I validate a variable: `validator::email()->validate($_POST['email']);` it doesn't work!

I try to check the content into `$_POST['email']` and it's: `hello@helloworld.com`

the exact output of `var_dump($_POST['email']);` is: `string(21) " hello@helloworld.com"`

Comment: What is the exact output of `var_dump($_POST['email']);`?

Comment: with the hello@helloworld.com: string(21) " hello@helloworld.com"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the output of `var_dump($_POST['email'])`, there is a whitespace in front of the email address:

```
string(21) " hello@helloworld.com"
```

So you have to remove that from your parameter, e.g. with `trim()`:

```
validator::email()->validate(trim($_POST['email']));
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, and the Respect library is actually correctly returning that it's an invalid email address. It should serve an error and the user fix it themselves. IMO